# Русские символы при выводе Graphiz

Tags: python, кодировка, graphviz

При построении дерева модели

```
def plot_tree(model, cols, fname='temp_tree.png'):
    dot_data = export_graphviz(model, filled=True, rounded=True, feature_names=cols, ou_file=None)
    pydot_graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
    pydot_graph.write_png(fname)
    img = plt.imread(fname)
    plt.imshow(img)
```

Русские символы фичей в выводе png файла отображаются неверно. Все фичи загружаются в кодировке utf-8.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как поправить

Comment: а можно вывод программы, который вас не устраивает, на каком-нибудь примере?

Comment: Добавил картинку вывода в шапку